# What does it mean by super(Application.class); in Java?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, reflection, super

The following code was automatically generated by Android Studio:

```
package com.example.hello.a;

import android.app.Application;
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class); // What does this line mean?
    }
}
```

What does it mean by `super(Application.class);` in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
super(Application.class);
```

calls the constructor of the parent class(in your case `ApplicationTestCase`) with the `Application`-class as an argument. For the documentation of this specific constructor [see the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ApplicationTestCase.html#ApplicationTestCase%28java.lang.Class%3CT%3E%29).

Answer (score 1):

it means that `ApplicationTestCase`, has a constructor that takes as parameter a `Class` object.

Snippet of the constructor you are invoking, from [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/test/ApplicationTestCase.java)

```
67     public More ...ApplicationTestCase(Class<T> applicationClass) {
68         mApplicationClass = applicationClass;
69     }
```

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationTest's parent, ApplicationTestCase takes a parameter object, a class. You call its constructor and gives it an Application.class.